# Upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 ended with text only mode

Tags: 14.04, boot, 16.04, upgrade

I wanted to upgrade to 16.04 from 14.04, so I run the command

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

Initially it was running smooth. During the upgrade, unfortunately I clicked the mouse over one underlying window on the screen. Strangely, the window did not come above. Instead I found the upgrade process was stopped. This was unexpected effect really. A message appeared to warn me the screen would go into very low resolution or something like that, then I was asked whether I wanted to repair or would continue, so I selected continue. Subsequently then another message told me that the screen would sleep for 1 minute.

I really waited for about 1 hour without any change on the screen that now turned to monochrome before I realized that the upgrade was broken.

After hard reset, it managed to boot but only in console mode (like Linux many years ago I used). I can log in using ordinary user account and can do `su` work, but I found that only loop back device was appeared, not `eth0` nor wifi device.

So please anyone would tell me how to continue installing failed upgrade. Please do not suggest a fresh install, because I have many material inside.

Comment: Can you boot into recovery mode from the grub menu? If so, try doing that and then select to fix broken packages. Also, it would probably be best to be connected to the internet using an ethernet cable while you do this.

Comment: Also, try running the following command: `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: @mchid: Thanks alot for your answer. The command works for my condition. During the process I met several conditions where error appeared and the system offer me to select such as:
** d11.conf (Y/I/N/0/D/Z) (N = default)
in this I selected default all until the the process ends (about 10 occurrence). My ubuntu version has become Xenial now

Comment: Awesome, I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Log in and attempt

`sudo service sddm restart`

`nohup unity --restart`

If that doesn't work attempt to run

`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

It may advise that you need to run `sudo apt -f install` to finish installing some dependencies.

Comment: I did try this before but failed and I know the reason. During the upgrade I noticed the process just reached to some 40% completion. I think it has not yet come to sddm or unity setup. Thanks anyway

Comment: You could try `sudo apt -f install`  and see if it'll complete.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you just need to run the following command to resolve this issue:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```